# Validate XML through XSD through Apache Axis

Tags: java, web-services

I want to validate my method which internally should validate the XSD before calling to service.

Below is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sendEmail(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        logger.info("Sending Email");

        String langValue = httpUtils.resolveLanguage(httpServletRequest);

        // SOAP Service Calling

         OrderExtraColumnsEntry orderExtraColumns[] = { new OrderExtraColumnsEntry() };
         String orderCustomerDB = httpServletRequest.getParameter("customerDB");
         int orderjobId = Integer.valueOf(httpServletRequest.getParameter("jobId"));
         int orderPrintId = Integer.valueOf(httpServletRequest.getParameter("printId"));
         String orderProduct = httpServletRequest.getParameter("product");
         int orderRecordId = Integer.valueOf(httpServletRequest.getParameter("recordId"));


         Order order = new Order(orderCustomerDB, null, null, null, null, null, 
                 orderExtraColumns, null, null, orderjobId, null,
                 OrderTypeEnum.fromString(httpServletRequest.getParameter("orderType")), 
                 orderPrintId,orderProduct ,orderRecordId);


        OperationStatus result = searchService.sendEmail(langValue, order, httpServletRequest.getParameter("emailaddress"),
                httpServletRequest.getParameter("emailMessage"), httpServletRequest.getParameter("emailSubject"));

        if (result.getStatusCode() == 0) {
            return "SUCCESS";
        } else {
            return "FAIL";
        }

    }
```

Above code, sendEmail() before calling to the service should validate the XSD.
I want that method to handle the xml internally which can validate the XSD.

Can you please make me to understand how can the xml object will get into picture to validate the XSD before calling the service?

Appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should validate the input xml of the ws called operation.
Show this input. 
What is searchService ? Show it please.

Comment: searchService is my service.

Comment: public OperationStatus sendEmail(String strLanguage, Order order, String strToAddress, String strSubject, String strBody){
  
  OperationStatus opStatus = null;
  
  try {
   opStatus = getCsrPortal().email(strLanguage, order, strToAddress, strSubject, strBody);
  } catch (RemoteException e) {
  
   logger.error("Unable to send Email", e);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   logger.error("Unable to send Email", e);
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ServiceException e) {
   logger.error("Unable to send Email", e);
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  
  return opStatus;
 }